# How to obtain the primary key of the selected row in bs_grid

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bs_grid to display a list of company names.  Each company name has a GUID identifier.  I define the grid as such:

```
$(function() {
  $('#grid1').bs_grid({
    ajaxFetchDataURL: 'CompaniesList.asmx/GetCompanies',
    row_primary_key: 'CompanyUID',
    useFilters: false,
    usePagination: false,
    columns: [{
      field: 'CompanyUID',
      visible: 'no'
    }, {
      field: 'CompanyName',
      header: 'Company Name'
    }],
    sorting: [{
      sortingName: 'CompanyName',
      field: 'CompanyName',
      order: 'ascending'
    }],
    onRowClick: function(event, data) {
      var selectedIds = $('#grid1').bs_grid('selectedRows', 'get_ids');
      // here I need the primary key of the row, not the row index:
      location.href = 'CompanyDetails.aspx?CompanyUID=' + selectedIds[0];
    }
  });
});
```

I've poured over the bs_grid js source and it's not jumping out at me how to obtain the data for a row based on the row_id.  How should I go about getting this information?

Comment: Doesn't each row have a unique id?  e.g. <tr id="tbl_demo_grid1_tr_41">.  Since your using jQuery, you could extract data like so: $('tr#tbl_demo_grid1_tr_41 td:eq(0)').text();  Where eq(0) would return the first column.

Comment: Found it!  Your comment helped me do it.  To get the row I use $('[id^=tbl_grid1_tr_]') which I then can parse the guid out of the ID of the elements

Answer (score 0):

OK, bs_grid expects the primary key to be an int.  This results in the GUID not being read correctly and data.row_id being "random".

To solve this, I had to add a row counter, starting at 1, to my results that I then use to get the UID of the hidden column for CompanyUID.

```
$(function() {
                $('#grid1').bs_grid({
                    ajaxFetchDataURL: 'CompaniesList.asmx/GetCompanies',
                    row_primary_key: 'RowID',
                    useFilters: false,
                    usePagination: false,
                    columns: [
                        { field: 'RowID', visible: 'no'},
                        { field: 'CompanyUID', dataClass: 'td_code hidden', headerClass: 'td_code hidden'},
                        { field: 'CompanyName', header: 'Company Name'}
                    ],
                    sorting: [
                        { sortingName: 'CompanyName', field: 'CompanyName', order: 'ascending'}
                    ],
                    onRowClick: function(event, data) { 
                        if(data.row_status == 'selected')
                        {
                            var row =  $('[id^=tbl_grid1_tr_]:eq(' + data.row_id + ')');
                            var uid = row[0].childNodes[0].innerText;
                            location.href = 'CompanyDetails.aspx?CompanyUID=' + uid; 
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```